# what is significance of implementing DocumentHighlightProvider for vscode extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

Could you please let me know what is the significance of implementing  DocumentHighlightProvider for vscode extension?
How we can see different kind (text/read/write) of word highlight in document?
Does each VSCode extension has default implementation?
Thanks
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

The document highlight provider is a special provider for marking code locations. It's not mandatory to implement one in your extension and no, there's no default one in each extension.

If you don't need the functionality of the provider simply ignore it.

Comment: Can you please explain more with an example ? I am not able to understand about code locations or text highlight ?

Comment: Please always ask only one question in a posting on SO. I understood your question as: is it important to have a DocumentHighlightProvider? And I answered: no. If you have implementation specific question then ask them separately. For each problem one question. And add what you tried so far in your question or you will not get any answer at all.

Comment: You mention about code location so I asked to explain more on that.Basically I want to know significance of implementing DocumentHighlightProvider for vscode extension ?